# Spring Boot is not creating tables automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm facing an error when Spring Boot try to insert data in a table. I'm using H2 and Spring Boot 2.5.0. It's seems that Spring is not creating the table.

Here is my entity

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    // Serial

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String email;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

And my repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {

}
```

I have added to my pom.xml `h2` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.

When I start the server in debug mode I got this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/PATH/target/classes/data.sql]: INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email) VALUES (1, 'Mitchell', 'Hudson', 'mitchell.hudson11@example.com'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabla "USERS" no encontrada
Table "USERS" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email) VALUES (1, 'Mitchell', 'Hudson', 'mitchell.hudson11@example.com') [42102-200]
```

This is my data.sql

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email) VALUES (1, 'Mitchell', 'Hudson', 'mitchell.hudson11@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email) VALUES (2, 'Melanie', 'Bell', 'melanie.bell51@example.com');
INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname, email) VALUES (3, 'Diane', 'Ruiz', 'diane.ruiz24@example.com');
```

I try some configuration in properties file but I wasn't able to fix the error.

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

I can see the query to insert data but it's not generating query to create the table so I think that the problem is there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you defined a repository interface that extends JPARepository?

Comment: @JAsgarov yes, I add it to the main post, I have other project with the same configuration but using Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE and it's working properly. I think that something change in the way of configure the project and im missing it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The *SQL Script DataSource Initialization* feature has been redesigned in Spring Boot 2.5.

> By default, `data.sql` scripts are now run before Hibernate is
> initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based
> initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use
> `data.sql` to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set
> `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to `true`. While mixing
> database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will
> also allow you to use a `schema.sql` script to build upon a
> Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via `data.sql`.

Reference

[Spring Boot 2.5 Release Notes - Hibernate and data.sql](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#hibernate-and-datasql)

Comment: I found it a few minutes ago and I came to comment it but you was faster. That's solve the problem!

I found it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts).

Comment: I am thankful for this (original question) and this answer to highlight the issue.  I am worn out from "been redesigned" spring data black magic voodoo changes.  10.9.2. Initialize a Database Using Hibernate


You can set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are none, validate, update, create, and create-drop. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded.   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-hibernate "it thinks"

Comment: @eHayik Thank you very much. I struggled for 2 days to resolve this issue.  lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a maven project, `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true` should be added in both src/main/resources/application.properties(for Spring Boot Application to run properly) and src/test/resources/application.properties (for mvn clean install to execute successfully).

PS: I am using Spring boot 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure adding dependence of h2 database here both dependence for
gradle

```
enter code here
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
```

maven  dependence

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop change to update it mean when rerun application or project your previous data in database will not lose.