# Why does H2 try to load data in database before auto-creating the schema?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm trying to load some data in my H2 database to do some testing. To do this I have a data-h2.sql file located inside my src/main/ressources folder. The problem is that these data are loaded before the schema is created (its my theory).

Here is my code:

Category.java:

```
[...]
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotBlank(message = "label is required")
    private String label;
[...]
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;IGNORECASE=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

server.error.include-message=always
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
```

data-h2.sql:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!50503 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

INSERT INTO `category` VALUES
    ('Jeu video'),
    ('Informatique'),
    ('Electronique'),
    ('Jeu de société'),
    ('Electroménager'),
    ('Littérature'),
    ('Multimédia'),
    ('Loisirs');
```

dependencies pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Dev/WorkSpaces/STS-4/ECommerce_SpringBoot/target/classes/data-h2.sql]: INSERT INTO `category` VALUES ('Jeu video'), ('Informatique'), ('Electronique'), ('Jeu de société'), ('Electroménager'), ('Littérature'), ('Multimédia'), ('Loisirs'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CATEGORY" non trouvée
Table "CATEGORY" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO `category` VALUES ('Jeu video'), ('Informatique'), ('Electronique'), ('Jeu de société'), ('Electroménager'), ('Littérature'), ('Multimédia'), ('Loisirs') [42102-200]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.7.jar:5.3.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:337) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1336) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1325) ~[spring-boot-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
    at zit.demo.ecommerce_springboot.ECommerceSpringBootApplication.main(ECommerceSpringBootApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/C:/Dev/WorkSpaces/STS-4/ECommerce_SpringBoot/target/classes/data-h2.sql]: INSERT INTO `category` VALUES ('Jeu video'), ('Informatique'), ('Electronique'), ('Jeu de société'), ('Electroménager'), ('Littérature'), ('Multimédia'), ('Loisirs'); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CATEGORY" non trouvée
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi & welcome! it *is* weird! 2 questions: Which spring-boot version? 2 dbs (h2 + mysql)? 2 remarks: it should be rather [`spring.datasource.platform=h2` (?)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) (but that seems not to be the problem). It comes from devtools (restart). And a (closed, "superseded", 2019) [spring-issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18829) (connected to multiple DS!).

Comment: H2 can be case sensitive, see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10793358/8158692) doesn't guide you toward a solution.

Comment: What makes you think that that SQL script gets executed?  Have you told Spring or Hibernate about it in some way?

Comment: @SteveEbersole if you place a data.sql file inside your ressources folder it get executed automaticaly when you run the application.

Comment: @BaptisteBeauvais to get rid of the case sensitivity i added IGNORECASE=TRUE; in the spring.datasource.url property, it didnt solve the problem tho.

Comment: Apparently not (`spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`) ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok i found the solution here [Spring Boot is not creating tables automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678311/spring-boot-is-not-creating-tables-automatically)

> By default, data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is
> initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based
> initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use
> data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set
> spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true.

Problem solved by adding `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true` in *application.properties* file.

Comment: You saved me one hour of debugging, and several more roaming around the infamongous Spring documentation :p. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

For Spring boot 2.4X and later releases things has been changed a bit.

1. `data.sql` scripts runs before hibernate is initialized. that means if you have this file in class-path and you do not have the schemas created already, then Spring errors out saying `schema` does not exist.
2. As answered by many others, we can use below property to defer the initialization after hibernate has already created the schemas.

   `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`
3. Above addition does the job for in memory databases. However, if you are using other databases like PostGresSql or mysql, you have to add below property as well.

```
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
```