# Spring boot application unable to execute insert statement from data.sql thrrows exception | table not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to create a simple SpringDataJPA application. I am using H2 database. After annotating the model class with @entity annotation the table is successfully created in H2 DB and the same can be viewed through the h2-console. however to initialise the table i am trying to insert the values from data.sql but while starting the application the error indicates that the table is not being found . Why is the table not being found when I am able to view the ?

[POM.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEPrn.png)

[Model Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDcC4.png)

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDfdN.png)

[data.sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf0Ct.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDg4x.png)

Comment: please dont post links - post actual code. Anyways this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678311/spring-boot-is-not-creating-tables-automatically

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.5.0 changed the way schema.sql and data.sql are handled.

You have to set

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

to make your example work.

Please read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon !!!! :) I made the changes as suggested and it did work!!! Yayyyyy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using latest version of Spring Boot please enable spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).