# Spting Boot with Graphql Error : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException Table not found in h2 Database

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, h2

I implement an example of **Spring Boot** with **Graphql** by using the **h2** database.

After I ran the program, I tried to create all **tables** automatically but I have a problem there.

I didn't solve it although I redefined the URL in **application.yml** and gave the name for each entity.

Here is my application.yml file which is shown below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: springbootgraphql
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 2000
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
    generate-ddl: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
server:
  port : 8081

# http://localhost:8081/graphql
graphql:
  servlet:
    mapping: /graphql
```

Here is my **error** which is shown below.

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "hospital" not found; SQL statement:
insert into hospital (id, name) values (1, 'Hospital 1') [42102-200]
```

Here is my **project** link : [My Project](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootgraphql)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67678311/spring-boot-is-not-creating-tables-automatically) it may give you the solution

> By default, data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is
> initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based
> initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use
> data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set
> spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true. While mixing
> database initialization technologies is not recommended, this will
> also allow you to use a schema.sql script to build upon a
> Hibernate-created schema before it’s populated via data.sql.

you'll have to convert `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization` to yml tho.